# forbid every request to a domain

Tags: .htaccess, security, virus

I have someone who came to me for help with a website having virus problem. Every time a new user was going to the website, a request to an external domain was showing a popup for an important chrome update which you can guess was making download a virus.

So I tried to work on it but the problem is that his website is a nightmare developed by a monkey, I never saw such an incomprehensible organisation with 8000 files of copy/paste code for just a simple website of 30 page without administration or even database.

So I managed to convince the customer to remake his website but he want me to block the virus while developing it.

Does anyone have a good idea of how i could forbid every request to the domain please, `htaccess` or any other method?

Comment: If the website sends a link to the client, you can't prevent the client from downloading it if it chooses to do so. The only real fix here is to not send malicious links, unfortunately.

Comment: @GaborLengyel it's not the link itself i want to block but the script that is loading the whole trap, there as to be somewhere something like <script src="domain/script.js"> do i have a way to tell my website to never allow request to domain ?